# jquery: wrap image in a div and copy the float from the image to the div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image that I need to wrap in a div:

currently doing this:

```
$('.photo-img').wrap('<div class="photo-wrap" />');
```

And then I need to take the float setting from the img and add it to the new div.

This the the HTML:

```
<img class="photo-img" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 0px; float: right; width: 200px; height: 267px;" src="path/to/image.jpg" alt="">
```

and this is what I need it to be:

```
<div class="photo-wrap" style="float: right;">
   <img class="photo-img" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 0px; float: right; width: 200px; height: 267px;" src="path/to/image.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Any help will be much apprciated.

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var img = $('.photo-img');

img.wrap('<div class="photo-wrap" />').parent().css('float', img.css('float'));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GEuLA/).

...or alternatively...

```
$('.photo-img')
 .parent()
 .css('float', function() { return $(this).find('.photo-img').css('float'); })
```

Comment: Thats Alex. I tried the first but ended up with float: none;

any ideas?

Comment: @cybercampbell: Only if your image had `float: none`. Inspect the source in the fiddle, you can see it produces the DOM structure you desire :)

Comment: my image definitely has float: right. I copied the code above directly from my site.

Comment: ok.. I created a new page and had only 1 image and it works perfect!

but...

as soon as I add a second image (one float left and the other float right)... both floated left.

does that spark any ideas on this issue.

thanks in advance

Comment: I should add that this needs to work on all images with the class.

Comment: You can't set up two images with the same class, and have two different floats on those two images, one right and one left, and expect both floats to be applied to one single parent class as needed, it's not possible. On second thought, anything is probably possible, but doing it that way is so much harder than just using different classes for the floats.

Comment: but the floats are inline not defind in the css. Is that still the case?

Comment: This is what ended up working:

`$('.photo-img')
 .wrap('<div class="photo-wrap" />')
 .parent()
 .css('float', function() { return $(this).find('.photo-img').css('float'); })`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.photo-img').wrap('<div class="photo-wrap" />');
var imgFloat = $('.photo-img').css('float');
$('.photo-wrap').css("float", imgFloat);
```

EDIT:

Writing something on a whim, not testet, but I think something like this might work:

```
$('.photo-img').each(function() {
     var imgFloat = $(this).css('float');
     $(this).wrap('<div class="photo-wrap" style="float:' + imgFloat + '"/>');
});
```

Comment: same outcome as above: float: none;

Comment: Hi Adeneo, Do you have any suggestions for this? I'm really stuck here.